# Highest value of the rank for a grouped data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ranking-functions

From the Data given below (Table : timeFramesDetail)

| tfgroup | City | activeDTTM | Begin_time | End_time | RankOfTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 16 | 2021-04-05 02:30:03.510 | 2021-04-04 18:00:00.000 | 2021-04-05 06:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 2 | 16 | 2021-04-05 02:30:04.510 | 2021-04-04 18:00:00.000 | 2021-04-05 06:00:00.000 | 2 |
| 3 | 16 | 2021-04-06 02:30:04.667 | 2021-04-05 18:00:00.000 | 2021-04-06 06:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 3 | 16 | 2021-04-06 02:30:05.433 | 2021-04-05 18:00:00.000 | 2021-04-06 06:00:00.000 | 2 |
| 3 | 16 | 2021-04-06 02:30:10.777 | 2021-04-05 18:00:00.000 | 2021-04-06 06:00:00.000 | 3 |
| 3 | 16 | 2021-04-06 02:30:11.667 | 2021-04-05 18:00:00.000 | 2021-04-06 06:00:00.000 | 4 |
| 4 | 16 | 2021-04-07 03:27:31.977 | 2021-04-06 18:00:00.000 | 2021-04-07 06:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 4 | 16 | 2021-04-07 03:27:59.523 | 2021-04-06 18:00:00.000 | 2021-04-07 06:00:00.000 | 2 |
| 4 | 16 | 2021-04-07 03:28:30.283 | 2021-04-06 18:00:00.000 | 2021-04-07 06:00:00.000 | 3 |
| 4 | 16 | 2021-04-07 03:28:31.257 | 2021-04-06 18:00:00.000 | 2021-04-07 06:00:00.000 | 4 |
| 4 | 16 | 2021-04-07 03:28:35.617 | 2021-04-06 18:00:00.000 | 2021-04-07 06:00:00.000 | 5 |
| 4 | 16 | 2021-04-07 03:28:54.837 | 2021-04-06 18:00:00.000 | 2021-04-07 06:00:00.000 | 6 |
| 4 | 16 | 2021-04-07 03:29:35.807 | 2021-04-06 18:00:00.000 | 2021-04-07 06:00:00.000 | 7 |
| 4 | 16 | 2021-04-07 03:30:34.793 | 2021-04-06 18:00:00.000 | 2021-04-07 06:00:00.000 | 8 |

How to find the highest value rank of all tfGroups?
Following should be the outcome :

| tfgroup | City | activeDTTM | Begin_time | End_time | RankOfTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 16 | 2021-04-05 02:30:04.510 | 2021-04-04 18:00:00.000 | 2021-04-05 06:00:00.000 | 2 |
| 3 | 16 | 2021-04-06 02:30:11.667 | 2021-04-05 18:00:00.000 | 2021-04-06 06:00:00.000 | 4 |
| 4 | 16 | 2021-04-07 03:30:34.793 | 2021-04-06 18:00:00.000 | 2021-04-07 06:00:00.000 | 8 |

Following is the query I tried:

```
Select top 3 tfgroup  ,City, activeDTTM
From timeFramesDetail
Group by tfgroup  ,City, ActiveDTTM
```

This gives me accurate result for the first two for some reason and the rest is wrong.
Can someone please help me with the rectification of the query?

Comment: Please post what you have tried, table structures, and more help on posting good question:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `window function` to partition and select the desired rank as follows:

```
select top (1) with ties * 
from timeFramesDetail
order by row_number() over (partition by tfgroup order by RankOfTime desc)
```

Comment: Hello Stu, This query gives me the output for rank as 1 for all the tfgroups. Can this be altered to give the output for the highest 'value' of the rankoftime for all the tfgroups ?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - can you elaborate, see this [example fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1ec80890b0f7ff77a215c94fc8f47e1a). I didn't both with all the columns as the solution is just selecting the rows for the highest rank of each group. Can you explain what is wrong/missing in the Fiddle?

Comment: Hello Stu, My apologies! I was looking at the wrong table. But this is absolutely right and makes the output flawless. Thank you so much for your kind help! :)

Comment: `TOP 1 WITH TIES ... ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER` requires an extra sort, see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=88fe94997052ce502c9482078a7c2571

Comment: While that's unavoidably true, I would say it's negligible; testing with 100k rows, the logical reads performed by both versions is identical. If I marked down every answer on SO because it wasn't the absolute most performant of all possible solutions I'd have no rep by now ;-)